# Laravel 5.0 - Error Call to undefined method Illuminate

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I have an error while setting up the code

Call to undefined method Illuminate\Foundation\Application::bindShared()

Comment: Can you post the entire error message?

Comment: To fix it .i executed `composer update` and `composer dump-autoload -o` in command prompt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method `bindShared` does not exist anymore.

`bindShared` has been renamed to `$app->singleton()`